# In NSIS, How to set the size of the dialog box when using nsDialogs::Create 1018?

Tags: user-interface, dialog, size, controls, nsis

In Nsis, I'm using:

```
 ...
 nsDialogs::Create 1018
 Pop $0

 nsDialogs::Show
 ...
```

But the size of the dialog box doesn't fit my needs. How can I specify a length for x and y to this dialog ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to resize everything it is probably better to use Resource Hacker and `ChangeUI` but you can do it at runtime:

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh

Function mypage
System::Call 'user32::SetWindowPos(i$hwndparent,i,i,i,i 640,i 480,i 0x16)' ; Resize outer dialog
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
System::Call 'user32::MoveWindow(i$0,i0,i0,i 600,i 200,i0)' ; Resize inner (nsDialogs) page

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 10u 100% 10u "Hello, welcome to nsDialogs!"
Pop $0
SetCtlColors $0 0xffffff 0xff2255

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

page custom mypage
```

Comment: @Andres It's working nicely except the command buttons: cancel, back, next. They are staying in the same position, which is now in the centre of the dialog box.

Comment: @JoelShemtov You would have to move those as well (`GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 1` to get the handle etc.) but just using Resource Hacker is better...

Answer (score 0):

My dialog isn't tall enough for all the controls I am putting in.

I tried your two Windows API's and while they worked, the client area of the install overlapped and covered up the OK/Cancel buttons.

I eventually worked out "use resource hacker and ChangeUI".  It was much harder than I thought it would be.  So, here is a more detailed how-to.  I was deeply entrenched with nsDialogs NOT ModernUI.  So this is a how-to for nsDialogs resizing of a window created the same as in the examples.  ModernUI is covered above.

nsDialogs::Create 1018

1. Get ResourceHacker from Angus:  http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/
2. Go to your NSIS Contrib folder.  C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Contrib\UIs and copy default.exe to the same folder as your NSI script file.
3. Rename your local copy of default.exe to tall_UI.exe.
4. Open ResourceHacker, drag tall_UI.exe into the window.
5. Use the treeView to dig down into resource 105 and click on 1033.  When you click on 1033, it shows a preview.
6. What you have a is the code and the preview.  Take note of the first line of code...

   ```
   105 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 280, 162
   ```
7. Now click on the top edge of the preview window and stretch it to make it taller.  Note that the final number in that line got bigger.  Notice how there is empty space at the bottom of the window now.
8. There are four controls along the bottom edge of the dialog: a button, an invisible box and two more buttons.  Drag all of these down near the bottom of the window.  As you select each you will notice the red * marking which control is being modified in the code window.  Just get them close to where you want them.
9. Move the horizontal divider line.  It's skinny and hard to move.
10. You will want your buttons to all be in a straight row.  To get them exact, move over to the code window and edit the 3rd number from the end of the line for each of the controls.  To apply these changes to the code window, click "Compile Script".
11. Click on the big gray box to select then use its bottom edge pip to stretch it to the desired height.
12. Tweak the code or preview.  Hit compile a lot.
13. It's perfect, you like it.  Hit compile one final time.
14. Click "File" and "Save".  It will save your Tall_UI.exe as well as make a copy called Tall_UI_original.exe.
15. In your NSIS script, you need to add a call to ChangeAll early on.

    ```
    ChangeUI all tall_UI.exe
    Page custom nsDialogsPage

    Function nsDialogsPage
        nsDialogs::Create 1018 
        Pop $Dialog
        ...
    ```

That did it for me. You will do some trial and error, always hit commpile and save in ResourceHacker and then rebuild your NSI.  You may note that your dialog is bigger or smaller than the preview shown in ResourceHacker.  That is because NSIS does scale your dialog based on font size, DPI... stuff like that.  Try and retry till it looks good.

You will note that nsDialogs::Create 1018 matches the number in the 5th line of resource hacker:

```
CONTROL "", 1018, STATIC, SS_BLACKRECT | WS_CHILD | WS_GROUP, 7, 7, 266, 160
```

I did some testing after getting this demo together and the positioning and size of that 1018 resource does have an effect but I can't tell you why it isn't black.

Full code of my demo is below showing.

```
#Created with NSIS version 2.46 downloaded from SourceForge.net
#Based on "Adding Controls" section of user docs
# http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html#step-add

!include nsDialogs.nsh

Name "Launchpad"
OutFile "Master Installer.exe"
BrandingText " "
Caption "Launchpad"
RequestExecutionLevel admin
SetFont "Arial" 10
VIProductVersion "2.5.0.0"

Var Dialog
Var Button

ChangeUI all tall_UI.exe
Page custom nsDialogsPage

Function nsDialogsPage
    nsDialogs::Create 1018 
    Pop $Dialog

    # It will create a new dialog in the page and return its HWND on the stack. The result must be popped from the stack to prevent stack corruption. If the result is error, the dialog couldn't be created.
    ${If} $Dialog == error
    Abort
    ${EndIf}

    # ${NSD_Create*} x y width height text

    ## Going to use $0 for y of each new control.
    StrCpy $0 "29"

    ${NSD_CreateButton} 50% "$1u" 25% 12u "Product Manual"
    Pop $Button
    ${NSD_OnClick} $Button Manual_Install_Clicked
    IntOp $0 $0 + 18
    IntOp $1 $0 - 2

    ${NSD_CreateButton} 50% "$1u" 25% 12u "Product 1 Installer"
    Pop $Button
    ${NSD_OnClick} $Button Product1_Install_Clicked
    IntOp $0 $0 + 18
    IntOp $1 $0 - 2

    ${NSD_CreateButton} 50% "$1u" 25% 12u "Product 2 Installer"
    Pop $Button
    ## ${NSD_OnClick} ...
    IntOp $0 $0 + 18
    IntOp $1 $0 - 2

    ${NSD_CreateButton} 50% "$1u" 25% 12u "Product 3 Installer"
    Pop $Button
    ## ${NSD_OnClick} ...
    IntOp $0 $0 + 18
    IntOp $1 $0 - 2

    ${NSD_CreateButton} 50% "$1u" 25% 12u "Product 4 Installer"
    Pop $Button
    ## ${NSD_OnClick} ...
    IntOp $0 $0 + 18
    IntOp $1 $0 - 2

    ${NSD_CreateButton} 50% "$1u" 25% 12u "Product 1 Installer"
    Pop $Button
    ## ${NSD_OnClick} ...
    IntOp $0 $0 + 18
    IntOp $1 $0 - 2

    ${NSD_CreateButton} 50% "$1u" 25% 12u "Product 1 Installer"
    Pop $Button
    ## ${NSD_OnClick} ...
    IntOp $0 $0 + 18
    IntOp $1 $0 - 2

    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function ExecInstall
    pop $0
    ExecWait $0 $1
    IfErrors 0 ExecDone
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_IconExclamation "$1 $0 not found"
    ExecDone:
    ##Call Update_Install_Statuses
FunctionEnd

Function Manual_Install_Clicked
    ExecShell "open" "$EXEDIR\Manual\Manual.PDF"
FunctionEnd

Function Product1_Install_Clicked
    Exec "Explorer.exe $EXEDIR\Support Files"
FunctionEnd

Function Product2_Install_Clicked
    Push "$EXEDIR\Product2 Folder\Product2 Installer.exe"
    Call ExecInstall
FunctionEnd

Section

SectionEnd
```